# Layperson's explanation of Bochner (1926) Almost periodic function definition

Tags: definition, almost-periodic-functions, quasiperiodic-function

I am trying to formulate a problem mathematically for which I have to mathematically formulate pseudo-periodic time series. According to this [research paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/44/90/85/PDF/Martin-N_Mailhes-C_CM10_V6_97.pdf), Almost-periodic and pseudo-periodic signals are similar.

**I am not able to completely understand the below mathematical definitions of almost periodic functions. I tried to write them in simple terms below. However, I wanted your help to correct me if my interpretation is wrong.**

> Layperson's summary of almost-periodic functions in terms of time series

Take very small repeated segment's (referred as sequence in definition) of a modified time series (I think it's called a translation) with a approximate period denoted by epsilon where epsilon or period is greater than zero. If the similarity between big chunk of these consecutive sequences (referred as sub-sequences in definition) in terms of period and shape is less than epsilon than the whole time series is called pseudo-periodic time series.

[Research paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/44/90/85/PDF/Martin-N_Mailhes-C_CM10_V6_97.pdf) mathematically defined almost-periodic signal by following the original definition proposed by H. Bohr (1947):

[image]

However, on [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function) the same equation is shown by Bohr (1925) and Bochner (1926):

[image: wiki]